# RailsTutorial 10.1 giving persistent "undefined local variable or method 'authenticate'" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I am very new to programming, and so far I've had no big issues with Rails Tutorial.

But when I hit 10.1, I started getting the same errors over and over again and I'm not sure why. I have looked up similar issues at the RailsTutorial Get Satisfaction group [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/listing_10_15_causes_user_validation_failure_running_rspec).

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Failures:**

```
1) UsersController GET 'edit should be successful
   Failure/Error: get :edit, :id => @other_user
   undefined local variable or method `authenticate' for #<UsersController:0x270dc60>
   # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:115:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UsersController GET 'edit should have right title
   Failure/Error: get :edit, :id => @other_user
   undefined local variable or method `authenticate' for #<UsersController:0x1ff7aac>
   # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:120:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Here's the spec documentation:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'show'" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user.id
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should find the right user" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      assigns(:user).should == @user
    end

    it "should have the right title, the user's name" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector('title', :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should have the user's name" do #in the body of the profile
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
    end

    it "should have a profile image" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector('h1>img', :class => "gravatar")
    end  

    it "should have the right URL" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should have_selector('td>a', :content => user_path(@user),
                                            :href    => user_path(@user))
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
    end  
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    before(:each) do
      @attr = {:name => "", :email => "", :password => "", 
               :password_confirmation => ""}
    end 

    it "should not create a user" do
      lambda do
        post :create, :user => @attr
      end.should_not change(User, :count)
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      post :create, :user => @attr
      response.should have_selector('title', :content=> "Sign up")     
    end 

    it "should render the 'new' page" do
      post :create, :user => @attr
      response.should render_template('new')
    end   

    describe "success" do
      before(:each) do
        @attr={ :name => "A Chowdhury", :email => "achowdhury@gmail.com", 
                :password => "cqsoqaqa", :password_confirmation => "cqsoqaqa"}
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        lambda do
          post :create, :user => @attr
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
      end    

      it "should sign the user in" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        controller.should be_signed_in
      end

      it "should redirect to the user 'show' page" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
      end 

      it "should have a welcome message" do
        post :create, :user => @attr
        flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i
      end   
    end     
  end

  describe "GET 'edit" do

    before(:each) do
      @other_user = Factory(:user)
      test_sign_in(@other_user)
    end  

    it "should be successful" do
      get :edit, :id => @other_user
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have right title" do
      get :edit, :id => @other_user
      response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Edit user")
    end  
  end    
end
```

**And the Users Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user= User.new
    @title= "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) 
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = "Edit user"
  end       
end

Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Joynul Choudhury"
  user.email                 "jcny816@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

**UPDATE: authenticate method in User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-zA-Z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence    => true,
                   :length      => { :maximum => 50 }

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with=> email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  validates :password, :presence     => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length       => { :within => 6..40 } 

  before_save :encrypt_password 

  # Return true if the user's password matches the submitted password.
  def has_password?(submitted_password)
      # Compare encrypted_password with the encrypted version of
      # submitted_password.
      encrypted_password==encrypt(submitted_password)
  end  

  def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)  
    user= find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end 

  def User.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt) 
    user = find_by_id(id) 
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.salt == cookie_salt
  end              

  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end  
end
```

Comment: "Dumb" question, but do you have an `authenticate` method somewhere that you haven't shared with us?

Comment: Hi corey, I do have an authenticate method defined in the User model, I just included that for you. Any insights?

Answer (score 3):

It's looking for an `authenticate` method in your `UsersController` and not finding one. It is defined in [Listing 10.11 in Section 10.2](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3aprotecting_pages).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an identical error.   After 30 minutes I realized I had miss-named the file:

```
  app/views/users/edit.html.erb
```

as

```
  app/views/users/edit.html.rb
```

Renamed the file with the expected extension. Saved.  rspec passed.

Hope that helps -

Perry